# PhpStorm почему нельзя выбрать php 7.2 ? Хотя он у меня установлен. Скриншот внутри. Как это исправить?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Я установил себе php версии 7.2 (я пользуюсь Open Server). В PhpStorm для CLI Interpreter я смог ее выбрать, а вот для PHP language level не могу. Почему так? Как исправить?

Вот скриншоты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: шторм синкает версию с `composer.json` а там видимо указана другая. или укажите в композере или отключите синк как в аналогичном вопросе на английском https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272977/phpstorm-ignores-php-version-setting-in-project

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите файл composer.json своего проекта. Если в нем стоит зависимость

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1",
```

то PHPStorm не даст вам выбрать версию 7.2

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.2 поддерживается начиная с версии PhpStorm 2017.2.1.

Comment: У меня 2017.2
http://ibb.co/gpmWAx

Comment: Уточнил. Поддержка появилась в первом патче: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/08/phpstorm-2017-2-1-is-here/